# How to put a string-array resource inside a thread that extends the Worker class and make it usable as a string?

Tags: java, android

I want to use the string-array resource inside the Worker thread by putting it in a String[] array but it gives me a "null object reference" result in the Logcat. How should I get the string-array resource to a thread without resulting to "null object reference" and make the data usable as a string?

**MyWorker.java *extending Worker class***

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {

    Context context = (Context) getApplicationContext();

    public DTipsDB myDb;
    int arrayIndex = 0;
    String[] tipsArray = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tipsOfTheDay);




    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        myDb = new DTipsDB(getApplicationContext());
        StoreAndNotify();
        return Result.SUCCESS;
    }

    private int generateNum() {
        Random r = new Random();
        arrayIndex = r.nextInt(tipsArray.length);
        return arrayIndex;
    }

    private void StoreAndNotify() {
        myDb.addData(tipsArray[generateNum()]);
        int m = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
        Intent repeating_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DailyTips_Activity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getApplicationContext());
        stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(repeating_intent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.lightbulbpng)
                .setContentTitle("Hackuna:Tip of the day!")
                .setContentText(tipsArray[generateNum()])
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(tipsArray[generateNum()]))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationManager.notify(m, builder.build());
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
        at org.company.app.MyWorker.(MyWorker.java:23)
```

Comment: You can't use `getApplicationContext()` there. Move that stuff into `doWork()`, or into one of the methods called from there.

Comment: Thank you so much @MikeM.! This solved my problem. I just put all the codes that need getApplicationContext() inside the doWork() function.